# How to update the OSM data in a PGRouting Database built with osm2pgrouting?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I'm using a PGRouting database originally built with osm2pgrouting from a *.osm file downloaded from Mapzen.

If I want to update the OSM data in that database, ie. re-build my PGRouting Database, what's the best workflow to accomplish this?

Also: I'm not married to the manual download of the *.osm file, so a solution involving osm2pgsql would be fine with me too.

Comment: I'm currently trying to work on the same thing. I have yet to find a working solution, but I suspect it is something along the lines of: obtain preliminary osm.pbf -> osm2pgsql -> (change sets can be applied here with Osmosis `--read-replication-interval`) -> *back* to a (changeset-applied) osm.pbf from PostGIS with osmosis `--read-psql` -> then finally use osm2pgrouting with a drop option. Essentially, you use osm2pgsql and osmosis to handle changesets to a non-pgRouting OSM PostGIS table, and then create a new osm.pbf to re-create your pgRouting topology from scratch each update.

Comment: However I can't actually get this to work, and examples are thin on the ground. Please update this question if you make any progress.

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup would the 'clean' option work? I'm going to pull the trigger on that soon just to see if it works - according to http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html, clean will " drop peviously created tables"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the 'clean' option does the trick, as per the [osm2pgrouting documentation](http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html#how-to-us) waaaay at the bottom:

all available parameters are:

required:
-file   -- name of your osm xml file
-dbname  -- name of your database
-user  -- name of the user, which have write access to the database
-conf  -- name of your configuration xml file

optional:
-host   -- host of your postgresql database (default: 127.0.0.1)
-port  -- port of your database (default: 5432)
-passwd  --  password for database access
**-clean -- drop peviously created tables**